# AOP pointcut error

Tags: spring, aop

I am using AOP in my application and need to define a pointcut,
I am doing that with spring configuration

```
 <aop:aspect id="aspect" ref="loggerBean">
    <aop:pointcut id="pointCut" expression="execution(public * *(..))"  />
    <aop:around pointcut="pointCut" method="logMethod"  />
 </aop:aspect>
```

but I am getting the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting '(' at character position 0
pointCut
^
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In your `aop:around` `pointcut` should be `pointcut-ref`.

Comment: how did I miss such a silly point, I had already made the bean so needed to use 'ref' for it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind the information you have provided, I've got two ideas:

1. Is the class that contains logMethod an @Aspect?
2. `<aop:around pointcut-ref="pointCut" method"logMethod" />` Notice the **pointcut-ref**.

I believe the latter is the right one but, can't check it now.

Comment: how did I miss such a silly point, I had already made the bean so needed to use 'ref' for it, thanks for pointing it out..